# Using multiple processes based on value in series

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cpu

it's been a while since I've used python's multiprocessing. I have a task that might benefit from it, or I'm incorrect in that assumption. I can only provide proxies for my use case.

Essentially, I am simulating a real-time input scenario. If the raw input is a video of a street scene, my input will be states of uniquely identified and tracked vehicles from frame to frame, e.g. `state_0: v_id=0; x=0; y=1; vx=2.5; vy=-3`.

These states will come one-at-a-time, not frame by frame. So if the above example was from frame 1, if vehicle 0 is tracked in frame 2 and a new vehicle is picked up, I will get:

`state_1: v_id=0; x=2.5; y=-2; vx=3; vy=-2.5`
`state_2: v_id=1; x=5.6; y=3; vx=-1; vy=0`

There is no frame information, just state after state.

The states are represented by a `State` object with a custom iterator that returns `v_id`, `[x, y, vx, vy]`.

I want to perform some analysis on these states using previous information for a given vehicle. Here's some more proxy code:

```py
self.analysis = {}

def estimate(self):

    for v_id, state in self.State:

        if v_id not in self.analysis.keys():
            self.analysis[v_id] = state

        state_estimate = self.do_something(self.analysis[v_id], state)
        self.analysis[vid].append(state_estimate)
```

What I have works, but I want to know if I can use multiprocessing to improve it. My notion was, can I send all states `v_id=0` to process 1, all states `v_id=1` to process 2, etc.

Since the `do_something()` function takes up so much time, I figured it would be faster if the `State` iterator hands out states to multiple processes.

I believe the iterator will be a bottleneck, because I'm not allowing myself to "look ahead" to any future state. But could I set up 16 processes, and based on the `v_id` of the current state, have the state estimate analysis performed  by a given process? Is multiprocessing appropriate here?

Comment: This is almost entirely going to depend on what `do_something` is. If it is CPU bound, then multiprocessing _may_ help. If it's mostly waiting for new states (or generally IO bound), then it probably won't improve performance much. But you'll have to either include details of that method, or just profile/benchmark the code.

Comment: To simplify, `do_something` is a machine learning predictor that uses past predictions and current state to produce a new prediction. I think it's CPU bound? Does that help? Sorry that I can't give actual code.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to try it out to know for sure. It's always a tradeoff. A new process is not free, and so you have to balance the creation and resource usage of those with any benefit to the computation. If the computation takes significantly longer than it takes for new data to arrive, then it very well may help to parallelize. I would recommend you try it out! Profile the code, parallelize it, and then profile again :)

Comment: But how do I do that? I've profiled the code so I know that the `do_something` is the time burden. I'm just not familiar enough with multiprocessing. Where do I create the processes in this code? How do I feed them the right data?

Comment: Take a look at the [`multiprocessing` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing). Your basic approach of sending data to workers based on IDs sounds good (as long as each ID is equally likely). I can't write the code for you, but briefly: create a queue for each process; push new states onto the queue; workers run an infinite loop waiting for new data on their queue, do their processing, and send or store the results however you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a stab. I've read the docs and don't have a clear idea of how to create and relegate work to the workers. I will put a modified example in a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware this won't work, but it's something.

<s>I'm struggling with how to feed tasks to workers if they are all running the same callable but with different `v_id`s and `state`s.</s>

<s>*first edit:* I think this is a bit closer to the mark, I have a queue for each process. The `state`s are added to queues based on `v_id`. Still trying to figure out the worker.</s>

*second edit:* Maybe I need both input and output queues? And maybe I don't need to track processes at all? Trying to base this all off examples.

In-progress solution:

```py
self.analysis = {}

self.queues = {}
self.n_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
for worker in range(self.n_workers):
    q_i = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q_o = multiprocessing.Queue()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=self.worker, args=(q_i, q_o), name=str(worker)).start()
    self.queues[v_id] = {'input': q_i, 'output': q_o}

def worker(self, input_queue, output_queue):

    ??? Maybe something here takes the place of self.analysis ???

def loop_states(self):

    for v_id, state in self.State:

        if v_id not in self.analysis.keys():
            self.analysis[v_id] = state

        queue = self.queues[v_id % self.n_workers]['input']
        queue.put(self.estimate, (v_id, state))

def estimate(self, v_id, state):

    state_estimate = self.do_something(self.analysis[v_id], state)
    self.analysis[vid].append(state_estimate)
```

Comment: You're on the right track here. The `worker` function should indeed include whatever function you need to parallelize. It should effectively be a while-loop that receives an item from the input queue, calls `do_something` on that item, and then sends the results back on the output queue.